# C# Как сделать ссылку на объект

Tags: c#

как мне пофиксить ошибку "Ошибка CS0103 Имя "SoC" не существует в текущем контексте."
знакомый мне сказал сделать ссылку, но как ее сделать я без понятия

```
namespace Killer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Process[] SoC;
            SoC = Process.GetProcessesByName("XR_3DA.exe");
        }

        private void kill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Process SoC1 in SoC)
            {
                SoC1.CloseMainWindow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EvgeniyZ при чем здесь "другая форма"? :)

Comment: @aepot Там заголовок вопроса такой, сам ответ разжовывает разные мелочи по доступу к переменным, включая ту, что у автора в вопросе (цитата: `Вопрос: А сможем ли мы получить доступ MyField из других классов, методов и др.?`)

Comment: Еще автору [на заметку](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/26077/)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно объявить переменную `SoC` не в конструктора, а в классе, тогда она будет доступна:

```cs
namespace Killer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Process[] SoC;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            SoC = Process.GetProcessesByName("XR_3DA.exe");
        }

        private void kill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Process SoC1 in SoC)
            {
                SoC1.CloseMainWindow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Поля в C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields).

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Process[] SoC;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
        SoC = Process.GetProcessesByName("XR_3DA.exe");
    }

    private void kill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process SoC1 in SoC)
        {
            SoC1.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Дополнительно, крайне не рекомендуется вставлять свой код в конструктор формы. Рекомендую использовать обработчик события `Form.Load` для этого.

Исправленный код будет выглядеть так:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Process[] SoC;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
        this.Load += Form1_Load; // вместо этой строчки можете назначить обработчик в дизайнере, а строчку убрать
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoC = Process.GetProcessesByName("XR_3DA.exe");
    }

    private void kill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process SoC1 in SoC)
        {
            SoC1.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
}
```